# Choosing Point to Raster vs Feature to Raster in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point, rasterization, resampling

I am converting point vector data to a raster dataset using nearest neighbor. I am using arcgis 10.2. The first step is to use the conversion toolbox, but there are two possible options:

- Point to raster
- Feature to raster

***What is the right application for each of these? When should I use one vs the other?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two comparable tools exist because ESRI has multiple license levels.  [Point to Raster (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000002z000000) is only available with the Advanced license.  [Feature to Raster (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000002v000000) is available with all of the license levels.

Point to Raster allows you much more control over how multiple points are handled when multiple points fall within a raster cell.  You get the option of most frequent, sum, mean, std, min, max, range and count.  Feature to Raster does not allow this flexibility:

> This tool always uses the cell center to decide the value of a raster
>   pixel. If more control over how different types of input feature
>   geometries are to be converted, please refer to the respective
>   specific conversion tools: Point to Raster, Polyline to Raster, and
>   Polygon to Raster.